# Python & SQLite3 You did not supply a Value for binding 6

Tags: python, sqlite

I apologize if this is redundant but I can't seem to find the answer. 
I've supplied all the values. Still it gives me error that I did not supply value for binding 6. This is My code

```
def Update_Employee(id,name,phoneno,address,nic,
joindate,email,picture,role,status,
salary,username,password):
  with conn:
    c.execute("UPDATE Employee "
              "SET emp_Name=:emp_name,"
              "emp_PhoneNo=:emp_phoneno,"
              "emp_Address=:emp_address,"
              "emp_NIC=:emp_nic,"
              "emp_JoinDate=:emp_joindate,"
              "emp_Email=:emp_email"
              "emp_Picture=:emp_picture,"
              "emp_role=:emp_role,"
              "emp_status=:emp_Status,"
              "emp_salary=:emp_Salary,"
              "emp_Username=:emp_username,"
              "emp_Password=:emp_password "
              "WHERE emp_ID=:emp_id",
              {'emp_id':id,
               'emp_name':name,
               'emp_phoneno':phoneno,
               'emp_address':address,
               'emp_nic':nic,
               'emp_joindate':joindate,
               'emp_email':email,
               'emp_picture':picture,
               'emp_role':role,
               'emp_Status':status,
               'emp_Salary':salary,
               'emp_username':username,
               'emp_password':password})
```

I've double checked the attributes in my database. Names\spellings are 100% alright and all the values have been suppplied.

Comment: you write with `conn` and then use `c`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes,I've  c = conn.cursor()

Comment: `emp_Email=:emp_email` is missing a comma. You do it a couple of times, after `password` too

Comment: Actually, you don't need it after `password` sorry since you have a space then WHERE.

Comment: Thanks bro
stupid comma

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63592114/1497139 for getting better debug info